# How to use Immer with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use Immer with my react project which is already using Typescript.
I couldn't find in the docs, or anywhere else, how to actually use immer with typescript.

What I have so far:

```
export interface IProps { }

export interface IState {
  names: string[]
}

export class ListNames extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { names: [] }
  }

  addName = (name: string) => {
    this.setState(produce(draftState => {
      draftState.names.push(name)
    }))
  }
  ...
}
```

this gives me two errors:

1. `[ts] Object is possibly 'null'`
2. `[ts] Property 'names' does not exist on type 'DraftObject<Pick<IState, never>>'`

[image]

Setting the type for `draftState` to `IState` won't work. What I've done that made it work was to cast the `draftState` to `IState` before I use it.

[image]

The thing is: I might want to use draftState more than one time, so it is at least inconvenient.

What's the correct way to use Immer with Typescript?

Comment: can you do `produce<IState>(draftState ...`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Sir, post it as an answer and you will have it marked. And thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the type definition for [`produce`](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer/blob/master/src/immer.d.ts#L35), it takes a generic type that is the state which defaults to `any`. Your TypeScript rules are set up in such a way that it thinks `draftState` could be null. You can specify the generic type to `produce` to specify what the state is:

```
produce<IState>(draftObject ...
```